# Can I read whole `AndroidManifest.xml` in annotation processor?

Tags: android, annotations, annotation-processing

I want to read the whole `AndroidManifest.xml` file content. Is there any way to read its content?

Comment: Where do you want to read it? In build.gradle or your source code?

Comment: @drulabs Read it in AnnotationProcessor.

Comment: @drulabs I am writing a library, so absolute path is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

AndroidAnnotations processor has [the code](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/blob/558b9088fdc2cd82988445ed86d60340b143a95f/AndroidAnnotations/androidannotations-core/androidannotations/src/main/java/org/androidannotations/internal/helper/AndroidManifestFinder.java), that does exactly that. Note, that instead of copying/reimplementing that code you might be better off writing a [plugin](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/blob/558b9088fdc2cd82988445ed86d60340b143a95f/AndroidAnnotations/androidannotations-core/androidannotations/src/main/java/org/androidannotations/plugin/AndroidAnnotationsPlugin.java) for Android Annotations main processor (their code already has few examples of such plugins, such as [OrmLitePlugin](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/blob/558b9088fdc2cd82988445ed86d60340b143a95f/AndroidAnnotations/androidannotations-ormlite/ormlite/src/main/java/org/androidannotations/ormlite/OrmLitePlugin.java)). The library itself is rather popular, so there is a good chance, that your users might have it in their setup and may even pass the path to AndroidManifest.xml to it via an option. So even if the above code fails, you would have a backup plan, that requires zero to little user's effort.